# How to use jobExecutionContext['key'] in job context xml file in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am working on spring Batch. I have set some parameter in job Execution Context as key-value pair in JobListener beforeStep method. I want to retrieve these parameter in my bean definition. But I am getting exception.

I configured this listener in job definition.

My beforeJob()  method is like..

```
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Before Member Number Import Job");
    log.info("Writing Failed File Header");
    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("date", DateUtil.getDateString());
    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("fileName", "dummy.txt");
    writeHeader();
}
```

I am using it to set resource property of FlatFileReader bean.

```
<property name="resource" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['date']}" />
```

I am getting following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:208)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:72)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:52)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:82)
at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:1)
at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:139)
... 27 more
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Without being able to see the configuration of your `FlatFileItemReader` bean, I have to assume that you don't have it configured as step scope...

Comment: Unfortunately due to project policies  I can't post. It would be helpful if you post an example.

Comment: You can't post the line that says `<bean id="foo" class="...FlatFileItemReader"/>`?  That's all I'm really asking for.

Comment: I got your point I used scope="step" inside bean definition. My problem resolved. Thanks for help

Comment: You might want to post the solution, and mark this as answered so people do not continue to review it, unless they the answer to this question.

Comment: Please post your answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

As they say in the comments, this is solved adding `scope="step"`

```
<bean id=".." class="..." scope="step">
    <property name=".." value="#{jobExecutionContext[..']}"/>
</bean>
```